# Monitoring connected hosts in a network via hub and wireshark

Tags: networking, wireshark

I'm trying to get all host/ips that my network is talking to, i.e. if one computer is accessing a website, I would get the websites IP, down to somebody deployed a trojan and is exfil-ing a file to some IP.

I tried connecting a raspberry pi with wireshark in promiscuous mode, but it did not work.

I read that if you use a hub, it will transmit forward packets to all of the connected devices so I'm thinking of doing something like.

MODEM -> HUB -> ROUTER -> WIFI/WIRED devices.

Then I connect my Raspberry Pi in the hub with wireshark in promiscuous mode, with the intention that all traffic coming in/out of the router is mirrored (passive wire tap). Would this do?

I want to confirm before I purchase a hub.

Comment: This is not a security question but a pure networking question.

Answer (score 0):

By "ROUTER" I assume you mean a consumer level router like a D-Link or Linksys right?

Those are really combination router, switch, and access points. This means traffic between devices which talk to the "ROUTER" will never reach the hub.  Only traffic destined to an external network will reach the hub.

You may want to try instead mirroring all the traffic your router sees on a specific port of the router, and monitor that port using promiscuous mode.

This can be setup in most routers using third party firmware such as OpenWRT.

Answer (score 0):

That should do, but it might be hard to get one in 2019: that would probably be 2nd hand. To catch the packets and their sources on the local network the order needs to be:

```
MODEM <-> ROUTER <-> HUB <-> LAN devices
```

You could first check if your switch has a feature called *port mirroring* or *monitoring port*. Managed switches usually have such features used for analysing packets or adding an *intrusion detection system*.